# how to scrape data from chart on https://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-bitcoin-addresses.html

Tags: python, scrapy

my code is

```
import scrapy
class CoinSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "coin2"
def start_requests(self):
    url = "https://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-bitcoin-addresses.html"
    yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
def parse(self, response):
         i=1
         for row in response.xpath('//*[@class="table table-striped abtb"]//tbody/tr'):
                
                i=i+1
                yield {                                                                             
                     'address' : row.xpath('/html/body/div[6]/table[1]/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[2]/a/text()').extract_first(),                                                                       
                    'balance' : row.xpath('/html/body/div[6]/table[1]/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[3]/text()').extract_first().split('BTC', 1)[0],                       
                    }
```

I would like to scrape data from a address and balance chart on https://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-bitcoin-addresses.html . I'm very new to python and do not know how to do this. I've looked at other questions in the forum but I was not able to do it

Answer (score 0):

1. You already got the rows and you're looping through them, so you don't need an index and you also don't need to complete xpath.
2. So the xpath for 'balance' is pretty straight forward, so I won't explain it.
3. Wallet:

The xpath for the wallet goes like this: we need to get all the text under the a tag, since it's divided between the a tag and span tags, so we use `getall()`.

But we're getting a '..' string from one of the span tags so let's remove it.

Also we just want the address and not the 'wallet: ....' part, this 'a' tag has a style attribute so we can omit those a tags that has this attribute.

Since `getall()` returns a list we just to to join it to a string.

```py
import scrapy
import time


class CoinSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "coin2"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-bitcoin-addresses.html"
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "table-striped")]//tr')[1:]:
            time.sleep(1)
            yield {
                'address': ''.join(row.xpath('.//a[not(@style)]//text()').getall()).replace('..', ''),
                'balance': row.xpath('.//td[@class="hidden-phone"]/text()').get()
            }

        next_page = response.xpath('//div[@class="pagination"]//li[last()]/a/@href').get()
        yield response.follow(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: thank you , Unfortunately, it takes up to 20 rows of data

Comment: @ali yes because you only selected 20 rows. See edit and please accept this answer if it suffice.

Comment: @ali look at the `next_page` part